# Is it possible to use the .NET version of TeeChart with C++?

Tags: c++, .net, teechart

[TeeChart .NET](http://www.steema.com/teechart/net) is a 100% managed C#.NET Charting Control. Would it still be possible to use the .NET version of the charting control with Visual C++?

I'm contemplating changing IDEs from Codegear to Visual Studio, so the legacy C++ code is obviously not C++/CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Visual C++/CLI` ?

Create a DLL on `VC++/CLI` and link dynamically with your main `VC++/non-CLI` project

Comment: I'm contemplating changing IDEs from Codegear to Visual Studio, so the legacy C++ code is obviously not C++/CLI

Comment: I recommend you to change. Impartially, VS is the leading IDE on Windows. Subjectively, it's awesome! Yes, it costs money. For first time you can use Express or find other ways. You will compile most of legacy C++ code without problem depending on it's compliance with VC++ standards. For example, I compile a lot of Linux ported projects if their developers supports Windows.